# How to remove multiple characters in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

ID               cityName                         Zip
1               ~!@#$%^&*Paris           _ab12345

How do I  show only Paris in `cityName` column and integers in `Zip` column. I don't know how to do it, I tried `regexp_replace` and translate but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult, you just need the proper regex

```
df.withColumn("cityName", regexp_replace($"cityName", "[^a-zA-Z]",""))
  .withColumn("Zip", regexp_replace($"Zip", "[^0-9]", "")).show
```

This `regexp_replace($"cityName", "[^a-zA-Z]","")` means replace everything but characters between a and z (both upper and lowercase by nothing)

This `regexp_replace($"Zip", "[^0-9]", "")` means replace everything but numbers by nothing

**OUTPUT**

```
 df.withColumn("cityName", regexp_replace($"cityName", "[^a-zA-Z]","")).withColumn("Zip", regexp_replace($"Zip", "[^0-9]", "")).show
+---+--------+-----+
| ID|cityName|  Zip|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|   Paris|12345|
+---+--------+-----+
```